# bundle exec rake db:schema:load not working in codeship.io

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, codeship

I am using codeship.io for testing my Ruby on Rails app. In the 10th step I am getting the following error. What changes should I make in the database.yml file

```css
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: database configuration does not specify adapter
/home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:52:in `resolve_hash_connection'
/home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:46:in `resolve_string_connection'
/home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:30:in `spec'
/home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:39:in `establish_connection'
/home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:175:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
/home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
/home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
/home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
/home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
/home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:173:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
/home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/home/rof/src/bitbucket.org/rahulv/luckily-beta/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
/home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
/home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
/home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:249:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
Tasks: TOP => db:schema:load => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

**database.yml**

```css
development:
 adapter: mysql2
 database: test_database
 username: test_user
 password: password
 host: localhost
 pool: 5
 timeout: 5000
production:
 adapter: mysql2
 database: test_database
 username: test_user
 password: password
 host: localhost
 pool: 5
 timeout: 5000
test:
 adapter: mysql2
 database: test_database
 username: test_user
 password: password
 host: localhost
 pool: 5
 timeout: 5000
```

Comment: Please show your database.yml file.

Comment: Please find the updated question.

Comment: Could you also paste the commands you run before running rake?

Comment: Actually all the commands are run automatically by codeship.io . I just linked my bitbucket account and pointed the app.

Comment: Make sure that your database.yml is actually checked into your repository.

Comment: No issues there i guess.

Comment: Did you resolve this? Seeing the same error